# necesito configurar una regla de firewall en pfsense

Tags: pfsense, ddos

chicos estoy haciendo una simulación de ataque DDoS utilizando máquinas virtuales (virtual box) ya logré hacer el ataque, sin embargo, necesito configurar pfsense para poder proteger mi servidor web de ataques ddos, pero no se hacerlo, me podrían ayudar por favor

Comment: plenty of results when searching for "pfsense mitigate ddos"

Comment: Please ask your question in English

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.